# Перехват переходов webview

Tags: java, android, webview

Как можно реализовать перехват перехода к примеру на google.com и открывать его не в webview, а передать открытие ссылки уже стороннему браузеру через Intent?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для вашего "перехвата" есть метод `shouldOverrideUrlLoading`

```
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
    if(url.equals("google.com")) {
    Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    i.setData(Uri.parse(url));
    startActivity(i);

    } else {
                view.loadUrl(url);
                return true;
           }
}
```

Для API >= 24 можно получить сразу `Uri` из `WebResourceRequest`

Comment: Мне нужно перехватить переход по ссылке в самом webview.

Comment: В методе `shouldOverrideUrlLoading` проверяйте ссылки. Вообщем, посмотрите, я обновил ответ

Comment: 'view.loadUrl(url);' запихнул в else ибо после нажатия всё равно ссылка грузилась в webview

Comment: ой, да, да, торопился прост :)

Comment: не забудьте, что `shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url)` теперь deprecated в API level 24. Используйте `boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading (WebView view, 
                WebResourceRequest request)` вместо него.